# Vue.js 2.0 Dynamic Props Docs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

js 2.0 and I'm stock in dynamic props.

See Image attached

[image]

My HTML code like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
      <input v-model="parentMsg">
      <br>
      <child v-bind:my-message="parentMsg"></child>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Component code:

```
    Vue.component('child', {

  props: ['myMessage'],
  template: '<p>{{ myMessage }}</p>',

})

var app = new Vue({

    el: "#app",


});
```

I know that data should be a function but how I'm going to implement it. I get this error on the console.

> Property or method "parentMsg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Answer (score 3):

I think message is clear. `"parentMsg" is not defined on the instance`. You have to define `parentMsg` at parent level. like following:

```
var app = new Vue({
    data: { 
       "parentMsg": ""
    } 
    el: "#app"
});
```

You can have a working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/m2v5y594/).